# Are these questions truly frequently asked?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta, sidebar

I was browsing Meta SO for a while. Then I noticed this on the right corner of the screen:

[image: "Frequently asked", with a list of questions that look unique]

I might be wrong, but these questions look like they're rather unique...

Shouldn't these be questions from the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag?

Comment: Well, it *should* be restricted to the [meta-tag:faq] tag. I wonder why it isn't.

Comment: Would you mind if I rewrote this as a bug report? I don't think those questions are the ones that are supposed to be there.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Sure, you can.

Comment: Outside of the first two questions, that certainly looks like the list of most frequently asked questions to me.  Pretty sure the first two questions are just there because they're featured.  None of the rest are unique though, those are all really frequently asked questions.

Comment: A very basic approach here is that a question is only asked once.  If anybody asks it again then that question gets closed as a duplicate.  So measuring the F in FAQ requires measuring how many users visit the question.  You see some that got a lot, typically because they are featured in the box at the upper-right.

Comment: @HansPassant Pretty sure this is actually measured based on questions most frequently closed as duplicates, not based on view counts.  So it *is* actually measuring which questions are most frequently asked.

Comment: Hmm, that seems unlikely given the frequency of "au festival" questions.

Comment: @StephenLeppik Funny, because the sidebar you added does exist and appears on all the pages (unlike the "Frequently asked" one, which appear only on Meta SO home page).

Comment: Ah, I'll change it then.

Comment: @HansPassant Like I said earlier, I think the first two are there because they're featured.  Everything after that looks like the list of most frequently chosen duplicate targets.

Comment: I'll also note that I think this makes up a *much* better "frequently asked questions" list than the FAQ tag.  Lots of the questions with that tag aren't actually that frequently asked about.

Comment: @Servy Makes me wonder where the one about comments on downvotes is.

Comment: @StephenLeppik I consider it a very horrible "canonical", so I'm glad it's not here, but the reason is because it's fairly new.  Most of these posts have been around for the entire site's existence, if not longer (pretty sure some predate the meta.SO split).

Comment: This list is detailed pretty thoroughly on [the other Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50242/what-is-frequently-asked).

Comment: For our amusement we should fill the front page of MSO with "au festival"  questions, if only to make @HansPassant go "*WUT?*" ...